# Solving a differential equation with a complex number as a coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the following differential equation;
\begin{equation}
y'' - iy = 0
\end{equation}
By following the usual method of solving, I get my characteristic equation $\lambda^{2} - i = 0$, which then gives me the general solution of 
\begin{equation}
y = cos(\sqrt{i}x) + sin(\sqrt{i}x)
\end{equation}
I want to know if there is any way I can remove the $i$ term from inside the brackets as to get real solutions. I have tried using an expression for $e^{ix}$ but cannot cancel out the $i$ and the $\sqrt{i}$

I also tried this with a similar ODE, as shown below,
\begin{equation}
y'' + iy = 0
\end{equation}
Where I got a characteristic equation of $\lambda^{2} + i = 0$, giving me a general solution of
\begin{equation}
y=e^{i\sqrt{i}x} + e^{-i\sqrt{i}x}
\end{equation}
However, I am still not sure how to cancel this out so that in cos/sin form I have no complex term inside the brackets.

Boundary conditions do not affect the problem at this stage - I'm simply interested in removing the complex term from the brackets.

I hope this is clear enough - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your solution is incorrect

Comment: Not really, it should be $y=f(z)=z_1cos(\sqrt iz)+z_2cos(\sqrt iz)$ for the first one, for example. Just a minor point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

$$\sqrt{i}=(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$$

then you can use

$$\sin ((1\pm i)x/\sqrt{2}) = \sin (x/\sqrt{2}) \ \cos (ix/\sqrt{2}) \pm \cos (x/\sqrt{2}) \ \sin (ix/\sqrt{2})$$

and then you know that

$$ \sin(ix/\sqrt{2})=i\sinh(x/\sqrt{2})$$
$$ \cos(ix/\sqrt{2})=\cosh(x/\sqrt{2})$$

Then you can perform a similar procedure for $\cos ((1\pm i)x/\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a real solution, taking the imaginary part of $y'' - iy = 0$ (and changing signs) gives $$y = 0 .$$